# Get user checkins from specific categories

Tags: api, foursquare

How can I get with foursquare API only user checkins from specific categories:

http://aboutfoursquare.com/foursquare-categories/parks-outdoors/

I only want users checkins on the beaches.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can only access the check-in histories of people who have OAuthed your application. You can't just query foursquare for recent checkins.

Once a user has authorized your application, you can query the **users/USER_ID/checkins** endpoint to get their check-in history. You then can page through this history looking for check-ins into the categories you want.

For example, you can see all the fields of a check-in object here:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin

One of those fields is a 'venue' object, which looks like this:

[image: venue-compact]

As you can see it has a 'categories' list. So just check this list for the categories you want. Hope that helps

Comment: I know to do oAuth, but seems that categiries are defined only by their names. I must wirk around :(

Comment: I found on Foursquare where you can find all categories: [link](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories) and when you check e.g. last checkins perform operation that would eliminate checkins from categories you don't want.

Comment: Categories have id's as well as names. See here for the full list: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/categories

Comment: Why this main categories that foursquare add has this long ID, do you know?